# Only absolute file paths in strace?

Tags: strace

Is there a way to force `strace` to convert all relative file paths to absolute ones?

The log often contains relative file paths like:

```
open("../surf/lh.inflated", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

Comment: This solution might help you: https://serverfault.com/a/727647

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

`strace` does not use relative or absolute paths when displaying arguments.  In fact, it doesn't know if the first argument of `open()` is indeed a file name: all it knows is that it is a null-terminated string, and displays it so you can read it.  It just displays the exact argument that the traced program used when calling the `open()` function call.